# pandas plotting barplot with secondary y-axis: misaligned on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a barplot with a secondary y-axis using a pandas DataFrame. The returned graph, however, is misaligned on the x-axis, as shown below

[image]

In other words, it seems that x=1 for the black curve is corresponding to x=2 for the barplot. Is there an easy fix for this? The data frame has the following values:

[image]

The code for generating the plot is shown below:

```
values = np.array([[ 5.8,  3.5,  0.7, 32.2],
       [ 4.8,  4.7,  0.5, 23.5],
       [ 4.8,  4.7,  0.5, 23.1],
       [ 4.6,  5.1,  0.3, 23.6],
       [ 4.4,  5.2,  0.5, 22.1]])

pdata = pd.DataFrame(values,index=[1,2,3,4,5],columns=['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'pie'])

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
axp = ax.twinx()

pdata[['a1','a2','a3']].plot(ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True,rot=0)
pdata['pie'].plot(ax=axp,color='k',rot=0)
axp.set_ylim([0,100])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])

ax.legend(loc=2)  
axp.legend(loc=1)
ax.set_ylabel('value')
axp.set_ylabel('pie')
```

Answer (score 3):

`df.plot(kind='bar')` plots the bars against `range(len(df))` and label the ticks with `df.index`. Since your index is `1,2,3,4,5`, you see that the line plot is shifted.

One work around is to plot `pie` manually:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
axp = ax.twinx()

pdata[['a1','a2','a3']].plot(ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True,rot=0)

# note the difference
axp.plot(range(len(pdata)), pdata['pie'], color='k')

axp.set_ylim([0,100])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])

ax.legend(loc=2)  
axp.legend(loc=1)
ax.set_ylabel('value')
axp.set_ylabel('pie')
```

Output:

[image]